# Android Studio java folder not created

Tags: android, android-studio

I created fresh install **Android Studio** on my Windows 8. ( i Added  system varibles **JAVA_HOME** in options) And java folder not generated , In my work i have Windows 8 too and it work's perfect. [image]

I tried many of methods, downloaded gradle.bin.zip and replace lib folder, replace all in .gradle folder, nothing help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be, that your folder to Android Studio contains a special character (umlauts like ö, ä, or similar). Uninstall Android Studio and reinstall it to a folder without these special characters.